# PHP: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-num-rows

I am working on a function, what returns whether a table exists or not.

But it always notices:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object [...] on line 10
```

in

```
1  function table_exists($table) {
2      
3      // get the database
4      global $mysqli;
5      
6      // look for tables named $table
7      $result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE $table");
8      
9      // if the result has more than 0 rows
10     if($result->num_rows > 0) {
11         return true;
12     } else {
13         return false;
14     }
15 }
```

the $mysqli var is set like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(mysqli_host, mysqli_user, mysqli_password, mysqli_database);
```

How to solve that?

Comment: Why do you want such a function? Don't you know your tables already?

Comment: Do you really want to see if a table exists? or do you mean whether the table has data in it? Using num rows is not the way to see if the table exists

Comment: you can change "if($result->num_rows > 0)" to "if($result && $result->num_rows > 0)"

Comment: it should be something like `show tables like '$table'` (you need the single quotes). You need to make sure you sanitize and property escape $table variable as well.

Comment: after debugging the code, @Orangepill is correct. You are missing the single quotes around table. And as he said, make sure to sanitize input $table.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i am making a user system and every user gets an own table :)

Comment: @tommyd456 yes, i want to check whether a table EXISTS. (look at my previous comment

Comment: @Scott thanks. this will prevent some mysqli errors.

Comment: @JuliusRickert this is what you are doing wrong. Awfully wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i now know it's wrong. i now have one table for all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left out the quotes.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE \"$table\"");
```

or

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'");
```

or

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE \"" . $table . "\"");
```

or

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $table . "'");
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL syntax is wrong. Check the value of your variable $table. You should have something like

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE "%"
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but % is not a regular expression and this code will return all the tables not just the one that the user is look for.

Comment: Well sure, I could have used "." or "*" for what matters... It's just a wildcard I've used instead of $table... If $table=% he will get the list of all tables, if $table=whatever he will get just that table. Ok nvm...